# Main.xml not loading when a loop of any sort introduced in Android code

Tags: java, android

Please refer to the following code, which grabs some information from a PHP script, and displays it on my phone:

```
package room.temperature;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RoomTemperatureActivity extends Activity {

    String result = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    TextView TemperatureText, DateText;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TemperatureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature); 
        DateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date); 
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //setValues();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            setValues();
        }
    }

    public void setValues() {

        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/tempscript.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }

        catch(Exception e)  {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }

        catch(Exception e)  {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result);

        String[] values = result.split("&");

        TemperatureText.setText(values[0]);
        DateText.setText(values[1]);

    }
}
```

This code works great when I comment out the for-loop, and just call `setValues()` once. However, as soon as I introduce the loop, `main.xml` (or anything on the screen) does not load until the loop is complete. I thought it had something to do with the activity life cycle, but no matter where I have tried putting my code, it simply is not working right. Essentially, I want the values to keep updating every time I call `setValues()`. A 10 iteration loop is just for testing the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand how the UI thread works to understand why you don't see anything until the loop completes. The UI thread contains a message loop where messages (you can think of them as small blocks of code) are pushed onto and executed serially (1 at a time). When the UI thread runs your code, it will do all that you ask of it but the values on screen will be "posted", or sent into the message loop to actually be placed on the screen at the next available time. You are not supposed to do long running operations on the UI thread, which is why the Android system has come up with multiple ways of dealing with long running operations. The most common scenario is to use an AsyncTask.

Http calls should never be executed on the UI thread, in fact this will fail on devices running honeycomb or later (unless you introduce some hacks in your code).

You should put your http calls in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the `doInBackground` method. Then set the `onPostExecute` method you can make your calls to the UI methods (.setText methods).
You'll want to put all the data into some kind of data structure such as an ArrayList in the doInBackground method.

Comment: But why does it work when I comment out the loop? How does the loop change the situation? Thanks.

Comment: what is the exception you're getting? Also, when you do Log.e, you can pass a 3rd parameter, the exception object itself and that will give you a stacktrace.. Do so like this, 
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

Comment: No exception anywhere, my layout just does not load until the loop is complete. Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand, thanks Matt. I will learn how the system works tomorrow morning, and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question, According to one of my seniors, When you make a request to change or redraw the UI, the call is made to the GPU to make changes
So when line one executes to make a change the GPU is notified and changes are made and control goes back to next line now in your case its a loop so its basically waiting for the loop to complete(loop inside a loop) and then repaint or redraw it

So I would suggest instead of placing it in a loop if you do like this

```
setValues(); // 1st Time
setValues(); // 2nd Time
setValues(); // 3rd Time
setValues(); // 4th Time
setValues(); // 5th Time
setValues(); // 6th Time
setValues(); // 7th Time
setValues(); // 8th Time
setValues(); // 9th Time
setValues(); // 10th Time
```

and see if changes are being made on each call(I know this is not your solution but it was just for understanding purpose)

And if I were to suggest a solution then i would say use an asyn task to do UI updation, because as of after 3.0 honeycomb any changes to UI cannot be done from the main Thread

Refer this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html for async task

Comment: This won't matter. The actual UI isn't redrawn until after your code ends. THus, when you call setText on say an TextView in android, the internal state of that text view will have the new text, but the UI won't reflect it until it gets drawn to the screen which will be after your current execution ends. I'm not sure if there is anything  different if your activity is being rendered with openGl though. I tested with ICS though and a basic activity that after the screen loaded, I posted a runnable that would update the text of a button in a for loop.. The text didn't reflect though until after.

Comment: @MattWolfe No, Matt has it right. I am working on a new implementation using a separate thread (aside from the UI main thread) to do the work I require. I realized that it's not that when I remove my loop that the app works right. It's just that the delay between calling `setValues()` once, and loading `main.xml` is so small, that it seems like no delay actually occurred. I'm glad I stumbled into this, and that Matt pointed me in the right direction. It's an important concept to understand.

Comment: @Capcom So you mean to say its the delay that is causing this  ??

Comment: Of course not, I am implying that the UI Thread waits for the HTTP calls to complete before continuing. The UI Thread is meant *only* to for displaying things on the screen. This article helped me understand the concept a lot, I suggest taking a look at it as well: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads