# Using AsyncTask, but experiencing unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Please refer to the following code which continuously calls a new `AsyncTask`. The purpose of the `AsyncTask` is to make an HTTP request, and update the string `result`.

```
package room.temperature;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RoomTemperatureActivity extends Activity {

    String result = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    TextView TemperatureText, DateText;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TemperatureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature); 
        DateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date); 
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          
            RefreshValuesTask task = new RefreshValuesTask();
            task.execute("");
        }
    }

    // The definition of our task class
    private class RefreshValuesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/roomtemp/tempscript.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }

            catch(Exception e)  {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine());
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }

            catch(Exception e)  {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //System.out.println(result);
            setValues(result);
        }
    }

    public void setValues(String resultValue) {
        System.out.println(resultValue);
        String[] values = resultValue.split("&");

        TemperatureText.setText(values[0]);
        DateText.setText(values[1]);
    }
}
```

The problem I am experiencing relates to the `AsyncTask` in some way or the function `setValues()`, but I am not sure how. Essentially, I want each call to the `AsyncTask` to run, eventually in an infinite while loop, and update the `TextView` fields as I have attempted in `setValues`. I have tried since yesterday after asking a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080358/main-xml-not-loading-when-a-loop-of-any-sort-introduced-in-android-code) which led to this code, for reference.

Oh yes, I did try using the `AsyncTask` `get()` method, but that didn't work either as I found out that it is actually a synchronous call, and renders the whole point of `AsyncTask` useless.

Comment: And what is the exact problem you are facing? error? or no output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `publishProgress()`, and `onProgressUpdate()` methods, to publish progress, while executing some task in `doInBackground()` method.

so change your code to following:

```
package room.temperature;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RoomTemperatureActivity extends Activity {

    String result = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    TextView TemperatureText, DateText;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TemperatureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature); 
        DateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date); 
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

         RefreshValuesTask task = new RefreshValuesTask();
         task.execute("");
    }

    // The definition of our task class
    private class RefreshValuesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream is = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/roomtemp/tempscript.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }

            catch(Exception e)  {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine());
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
                publishProgress(result);
            }

            catch(Exception e)  {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
             }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            setValues(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //System.out.println(result);
            setValues(result);
        }


    }

    public void setValues(String resultValue) {
        System.out.println(resultValue);
        String[] values = resultValue.split("&");

        TemperatureText.setText(values[0]);
        DateText.setText(values[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest move for loop from onCreate() to AsyncTask doInBackground(), so you don't need to create 10 AsyncTask instances.

Comment: @Wenhui I am trying this, and it looks like it will work, but I am experiencing a weird problem in Eclipse. My `setValues(values);` call is getting an error in the IDE, saying `The method setValues(String) in the type RoomTemperatureActivity is not applicable for the arguments (String[])`. I changed the generics type to String, as well as `protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)` so I don't see why I should be getting this error. Thanks!

Comment: Solution was to use values[0] because for some reason, it is coming in as an array of strings. Kind of odd, but it works. You forgot to change the generic type from Integer to String in your code by the way. Thanks, best answer chosen!

Comment: @capcorn It is not odd. `onProgressUpdate(String... values)` takes String Varargs as its arguments. Varargs is similar to arrays, but you can pass 0 arguments. Here is the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html